How do I change my gcc compiler and debugger in VSCode?
I need to use another compiler (gcc, gdb, g++) that I installed on my Win 11 box on VSCode.  How do I do that?

depends what other build tools you're using and what support extensions you're using in VS Code. please provide those details.

I have the answer.  After I clean installed mingw64 using msys2 I was able to wdit the json files to point to the location of my bin directory.  It worked fine.  Yet, there was a segmentation error that was caused by my avast antivirus... I added the exception and everything worked fine...
